# Play Framework reloads with any /public modification

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a web site that runs in a subproject via `sbt web/run`, but it recompiles the entire site and reloads the play framework any time I modify a `.js` file in the `/public` folder.  Is there any way to turn that off?  I'm running Play 2.4.6.

```scala
lazy val web = project.in(file("web")).
  enablePlugins(PlayScala).
  settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    specs2 % Test,
    cache,
    ws
  ),
  routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator,
  fork in run := true
)
```

There's an old issue, but I thought it was fixed in 2.3: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2905

Comment: Just hint: consider using some frontend server for serving public, static assets without putting them into app, this way you won't need to redeploy your app every time when want/need to add new image or fix some CSS/JS bug.

Comment: @biesior thanks, that will be a good idea for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had scalariform enabled in the top-level scope.  This was causing `.scala` files to be reformatted and then recompiled, but only when other files were modified.  Removing scalariform fixed it.

Comment: How to have scalariform enabled and do not reload sources? I think it is bug in sbt-scalariform plugin.